# Interpreting output from package robfilter (robust.filter)

Tags: r, filtering, time-series

I'm using the R package `robfilter` to analyse some time series data. More specifically the function `robust.filter`. However when I pass a time series of length 38 as an argument, the vectors that make up the output list are of inconsistent lengths. I would've expected them to be the same length, but possibly I'm misinterpreting the output. Here is an example

```
tmp1 <- c(21.40253, 21.71123, 23.62187, 23.34300, 22.81753, 25.05459, 19.13591,
18.75162, 19.92034, 19.98294, 20.07355, 19.76710, 18.87155, 20.06639,
19.69027, 21.33667, 21.57617, 20.84389, 22.28439, 21.73989, 21.82995,
23.02375, 21.99251, 24.88138, 27.75982, 28.84098, 27.67645, 27.04585,
27.16779, 25.62208, 25.90392, 26.92163, 26.83929, 26.83194, 30.43352,
30.95034, 32.41596, 31.87539)

length(tmp1)
```

The length is 38

```
library(robfilter)
tmp2 <- robust.filter(tmp1, width=7, shiftd=4, extrapolate=TRUE)
length(tmp2[["y"]])
length(tmp2[["ol"]])
length(tmp2[["level"]])
```

`y` which represents the original data is 38, but the vector which identifies the outliers is of length 41, and that which represents the filtered series is of length 40!

Can I assume for example that the first observation in "`ol`" corresponds to the first point in the original series? I would appreciate any insights as this inconsistent length has me confused.

In the case of the above series there were actually no outliers identified. So I have provided another example where robust.filter indicates there are outliers

```
tmp3 <- c(9.590999, 10.736618, 11.213917, 11.486491,  9.727762,
7.564208,  7.995007,  7.718619,  7.908130, 7.598344,  7.884147,
8.560636,  9.490633,  9.768715,  9.221128,  8.535356,  9.589786,
9.900386, 10.496643, 10.817289, 11.371327, 12.310138, 11.572224,
13.117717, 13.720533, 12.880585, 12.830893, 12.578935, 11.910936,
11.063447, 10.916194, 10.881677, 11.246900, 11.264994,  9.844785,
10.512842, 10.609419, 10.866941, 11.541334, 12.041648, 12.188250,
12.289139, 11.412508, 11.603581, 11.018384, 12.374552, 12.010114,
11.701049, 11.550803, 11.029398, 11.109258, 11.263335, 11.201110,
11.047172, 11.398097, 11.068206, 11.639072, 12.182218, 11.574394,
12.970866, 12.214502, 12.271814, 11.529558, 13.413776, 13.452780,
12.854925, 13.494725, 13.381464, 13.054178, 13.346170, 12.622088,
15.365530, 10.252811, 11.067396, 10.791832,  9.584768, 10.765442,
10.781584, 9.646298, 10.452633)

length(tmp3) #80
tmp4 <- robust.filter(tmp3, width=9, shiftd=4, extrapolate=TRUE)
length(tmp4[["y"]]) #80
length(tmp4[["ol"]]) #81
length(tmp4[["level"]]) #80
```

Again the vector which indicates which data point is an outlier is of inconsistent length.

Note this problem doesn't always occur. Often the lengths of the vectors are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Looked a bit at the source code and the file robust-filter.R and noted a few index values resulting from ceiling(m/2) and ceiling(m/3) that could result in the somewhat padded vectors. It seems that the lengths of the vectors $ol, $level, ect are related to the window size. For example, in the case given if the set size is 42, with window size of 7, then all result sets are 42 since 42/7 divides evenly.